# How to interpret "hier" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Weiß ja nicht, ob es an diesem neuen Politiker liegt, aber **langsam** wird es mir **hier** zu ungemütlich.

Initially, I was tempted to interpret this "hier" as "in this place where I am now", but I wonder if it is actually more like "at this point / now", perhaps related to the word "langsam" in the sense of "endlich"?

Comment: If this is about a politician, then "hier" simply means the area whose representative he is - probably the province or the entire country.

Answer (score 5):

- langsam = slow, slowly
- hier = here

> (Ich) weiß ja nicht, ob es an diesem neuen Politiker liegt, aber langsam wird es mir hier zu ungemütlich.
>   I do not know if it's up to this new politician, but **slowly** it gets too uncomfortable for me **here.**

The process of becoming uncomfortable is going on, and it is processing slowly. It has started in the past, is getting more and more uncomfortable, and it will go on also in the future. Uncomfortness is growing slowly, in small steps, and the end is not reached yet.

And it is getting uncomfortable here, where I am. In my favorite pub, at home, on my work, in my city, in my country. Here, at the place where I am.

Answer (score 1):

*Langsam* in this sentence is an adverb related to *ungemütlich werden*. The situation becomes *slowly more and more awkward*. You can translate *hier* with *here* in this sentence. There is nothing exceptional.